# Replace a file if path of the file contains a string in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

There are multiple locations where my file.xml resides. I want to replace certain instances of the file.xml with another file.xml. I can find all the paths where the file is present. Of all the paths found, I need to replace the original with the new one only when the path contains `process-server/config`

`find . -name "file.xml"` gives me all the paths where the file resides.. I only want to select few paths based on the condition to replace.

I am not trying to replace a string in the file, but replace a complete file if the path of the file contains a substring (to be more precise the end of the path should be the substring)

Comment: use `-path` instead of `-name` so you can write a pattern that matches the whole pathname.

Comment: Then i get the list of paths. How do I use the output of the find? Outputting it to a file and reading it line by line? Or is there a one liner that i can use?

Comment: You can pipe it to `xargs` to execute a command on all the matched files.

Comment: In this case the find output is not the source but the target. So if i pipe will i be able to replace the files from another destination to the destination from find?

Comment: Use the `-exec` option to `find`. `-exec mv otherfile.xml {} \;`

Comment: That worked perfectly fine. Thank you. Could you post this as an answer?

Comment: I think the linked question doesnt really answer my question

Comment: Why not? `-path '*/process-server/config*file.xml'`

Comment: The inked question is about finding full path and for me it is more about running a command based on the find result

Comment: That's not how I read your question. It said you know how to do this using `-name`, you wanted to know how to restrict the result to only the files that are inside `process-server/config`. That's independent of how you perform actions on the found files.

Comment: So it sound like you have two different questions: One is how to select only files with a certain pathanme condition, and the other is how to perform operations on all the files that are found.

Comment: Additionally, none of this is programming questions, they're just questions about basic use of the `find` utility. [unix.se] would be a better place to ask.